# Meaning of this phrase

Tags: meaning, word-choice

It is from an article entitled "I stopped drinking coffee for a week — and it made me physically ill"

I love coffee—black coffee, specifically. Cream or sugar only interfere with the flavor of my beloved drink.

Before this experiment, I usually had three or four cups a day. This usually consisted of two before I left the house, another one or two at work, and then maybe one later in the afternoon if I needed a pick-me-up. My office is right above a coffee shop, so you could say **I wasn't exactly set up for success.**

I am confused why the writer used the bold phrase. Does the writer want to quit drinking coffee? But, it doesn't mention in the sentences. Could anyone explain to me?

Answer (score 1):

The narrator wanted to try to stop drinking coffee. But because she/he loves coffee too much, it's physically hurt her/him to quit drinking coffee.
As for that bold sentence, she knew in the beginning that it would be a very difficult thing to do because access to getting coffee is so easy, it's right below her office.